# Dynamically change symbol in expression

Tags: python, lambda, operators, expression, code-generation

I'll be using a genetic algorithm to train some robots to play a simple game. I want to represent each gene with a tuple of constants and ideally have each gene run like so (pseudo-code):

```
#robot
genes = [(4,5,2,...),...]
actions = (move_left,move_forward...)
data = [my_x,my_y]
memory = [6,5,9,-2,...]

cpr = ('>','<','==')
agn = ('+=','-=','=')

def execute_gene(gene):
    if (data+memory)[gene[0]] cpr[gene[1]] (data+memory)[gene[2]]:
        if gene[3] >= 0: memory[gene[4]] agn[gene[5]] (data+memory+[1,2,3])
        exc = (genes+actions)[gene[6]]
        if type(exc) == 'tuple': execute_gene(exc)
        else: exc()
```

Of course this is fanciful I'll be trying to compare and assign my variables with strings rather than operators. So in which ways can I manipulate expressions and how?

Comment: Try to give some example and expected input and output.

Comment: What is an expression? Wht do you want to change in it?

Comment: @User An expression is analogous to a statement, e.g. (5,'a'+'b',6>3) are all expressions.